# Taylor Expansion of $e^{itx}$, Expectation

Tags: random-variables, taylor-expansion, expectation

the Taylor-expansion of $e^{itx}$ is

$$1+itx+(itx)^2 / 2! + \cdots.$$

My question:

Why can one write $1+itx+o(t)$ for the sum I sated above?

$o(t)$ would mean that $(itx)^2 / 2! + \cdots$ would be growing linear in $t$, but I do not see why this is so.

My second question: If the $x$ in $e^{itx}$ is a real random variable, why can we conclude that the expectation of $e^{itx}$ is $1 + it E(x) + o(t)$, or more specific (it is clear that we use the linearity of the expectation):

Why is $E[o(t)] = o(t)$?

Thank you

Comment: I am not sure, it is from this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pP0AgamsAsw

Minute 7:00, bottom left of the screen

Comment: Here, we say that a function $q(t)$ is $o(t)$ iff $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{q(t)}{t} = 0$. Sometimes, we use the same notation to indicate that a function satisfies the same limiting behavior as (instead) $t \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a useful estimate
$$
\Big|e^{ix}-\sum_{k=0}^n{(ix)^k\over k!}\Big|\le\min(|x|^{n+1}/(n+1)!,2|x|^n/n!).
$$
(For a proof see section 9.3 of Resnick's *A Probability Path*.)
In particular (take $n=1$, and replace $x$ by $tX$)
$$
\Big|e^{itX}-1-itX\Big|\le\min(t^2|X|^{2}/2,2|t|\cdot|X|).
$$
From this, upon taking expectations, it follows that $\Bbb E[e^{itX}] = 1+it\Bbb E[X]+O(t)$ (when $\Bbb E|X|<\infty$) and that the $O(t)$ term is $O(t^2)$ (which is of course smaller than $o(t)$) when $\Bbb E[X^2]<\infty$.